# Has anyone bought from BestPricePhoto.com?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, bait-and-switch-scam

Randomly came across this site, never heard of it before, has some good prices.  Almost too good.  Lots of buzzwords about being 'wholesale' and 'direct from the manufacturer'.  Price looks legit, but experience has taught me if it looks too good to be true it probably is.  Still, for this price, almost worth taking the risk.

http://bestpricephoto.com/h/product_info.php/nikon-d7000-162-mp-digital-slr-camera-body-p-19926?zmap=19926&zmac=2&zmas=1&zmam=80512835&csv=pg&osCsid=8725f24c7844b4a513c2942c35335063

Anyone bought from them before?

Comment: They're not on [Nikon's authorized dealer list](http://www.nikonusa.com/en_US/IMG/Images/Corporate/Where-to-Buy/Nikon_Authorized_Dealers.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

reading their website, it looks to be just another bait&switch operation.

> Email order confirmations do not reflect any additional merchandise purchased or order adjustments if made over the phone. New merchandise or expedited processing costs added over the phone will only appear on the final invoice you receive with your. No orders are processed or shipped on Saturdays, Sundays or Holidays. In the event of delays, we will contact you by phone or email. If the delay is due to a back order situation you will receive notice by phone or e-mail and be given the choice to remain on back order, substitute to another item, or cancel your order.

This in particular... Typical bait&switch tactic. Claim a delay, or a "helpful assistant" calling you about something "missing that you really need" (which is actually included in the box from the manufacturer) and offering it at extra cost (not appearing separate on any bill, just the amount increases, so you've no way to file a claim agains them) and failing to ship if you decline the offer (interminable "delays", leading eventually to an offer of a more expensive "alternative" and the whole circus starts again).

Also note they've no address information listed, only phone numbers, despite mentioning a physical store in several places. I'd be extremely wary of them.
As they say: if it sounds too good to be true, it most likely is.

Comment: "Contact Us" page does list an address - 2380 60th Street
Brooklyn. NY 11204. Google Street View does show a small camera shop there, albeit with a different phone number.

Comment: hmm, didn't see that earlier. And of course Brooklyn is well known for its shady bait&switch operation camera stores. Most if not all of them there operate the scams.

Answer (score 1):

[Reviews at Reseller Ratings](http://www.resellerratings.com/store/bestpricephoto_5) confirm that this one is a scam. There are a few examples of the classic accessory-upgrade hard-sell (where if you don't buy overpriced accessories, the discounted price which lured you in evaporates), and problems with delays and bad charges. There are a lot of one-liner positive reviews, but check this one out:

> "My order was not placed for over a week, so I called Customer service. They made me place a favorable review on the internet before they would even place my order.

*Yeah*. Even if you *could* get the good price after some hassle, I'm quite certain it's not worth it. Stick to B&H Photo, Adorama, and of course Amazon. These places all do enough volume that they have the *real* best deals and will not give you any trouble.